# Email hostnames in a group attachment rather than individual mails per server

Tags: ansible, yum

Regarding monthly patching, we currently have an pre_task mail notification sent out prior to the updates being installed but due to the {{ inventory_hostname }} being included in the body of the email, this is sent out on a per server basis.

Is there a way to replace the inventory_hostname in the body to reference all servers within the hosts group (in this case groupOne) so that one email is sent out with all hostnames rather than individual emails?

```
hosts: groupOne

become: true

any_errors_fatal: true

pre_tasks:

name: Notification email of patching beginning
mail:
    host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com

    port: XXXXXX

    to: hello@gmail.com

    sender: patching@gmail.com
    subject: Patching_Notification
    body: "Monthly patching is about to commence for {{ inventory_hostname }}. A further email will be sent on completion"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group_names` variable to get the group name(s) of your host.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic

You probably want to run your pre_tasks notification only once with `run_once: yes`.